# How to implement batch normalization layer for tensorflow multi-GPU code

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed-computing, batch-normalization

I have created a multi-GPU network as [Cifar10_multigpu](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py)

In the inference implementation, they said:

> We instantiate all variables using tf.get_variable() instead of
>     tf.Variable() in order to share variables across multiple GPU 
>     training runs.
>     If we only ran this model on a single GPU, we could simplify this 
>    function
>     by replacing all instances of tf.get_variable() with tf.Variable().

So I did it about all my conv2d layers as the example, but what about batchnorm layer? How do I implement it by myself?

Can I use `tensorflow.contrib.slim.batch_norm` in this case?
The example does not contain any recommendation about batch norm layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`tf.layers.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization). It also creates variables via `tf.get_variable()`, hence they can be shared as well.

In addition, it works seamlessly with `tf.layers.conv*` functions.

**Update**: [`tf.nn.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization) is fine too. It's a more low-level function that requires you manage `mean` and `variance` tensors yourself. In fact, `tf.layers.batch_normalization` is a wrapper over `tf.nn.*` functions, which also includes `tf.nn.fused_batch_norm` (a faster fused version).

Comment: @ Maxim 

thanks for your answer,in the above link it said I have to use  (tf.nn.conv2d),does (tf.layers.batch_)normalization works good with it too?

Comment: @ Maxim 
shouldnt I use (tf.nn.batch_normalization)?

Comment: @ Maxim thanks,so its not necessary for me to use tf.nn,batch_normalization,I can use tf.layers .batch_normalization and be sure for sharing the variables